# How to add GMT +530 to - M j, Y, g:i a format

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

How to add GMT +530 to "M j, Y, g:i a" format using php. I am trying to add the GMT +530 Like

```
M j, Y, g:i a +530
```

But not able to get the desired result.

Comment: `GMT +530`? or add 530 hours?

Comment: 5 hours 30 minutes ---- Asia/Kolkata time

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<?php
$date = date("M j, Y, g:i a", strtotime('+5 hours +30 minutes'));
echo $date;
?>
```